# "Role-playing Games" confusion

Tags: discussion

Check this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18851/where-are-the-different-games-tags-like-lineage-2-or-heroes-3

It's at least the second time someone has confused the site for computer games related and I wonder if the name, "Role-playing Games" is not a confusing one. Why not add "Tabletop" to the site title, or something like this, which would make the difference more clear on the first sight?

Comment: But its not just table top.  What about play by email, forum, irc, skype etc etc?

Comment: In my opinion play by email, forum, irc, skype is still Tabletop RPG, but played via different medium. Even FAQ states "Q&A by and for players and gamemasters of tabletop role-playing games". I don't know any other fitting name, though the way it is called in Polish translates to "Plot Game" or "Fictional Game", depending on what meaning you use ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It wouldn't help.

People who are that confused don't bother to read our fAQ or anything else before diving right in. Giving additional cues to them is like tossing bread pellets into a black hole. We close their questions (not downvote) and move on.

Comment: Still, the only place that it is explicitly written that the site is only about tabletop games is in the FAQ, not in the main page and not even in the "Ask Question". I can imagine someone not wanting to read the FAQ, since the first category, "What kind of questions can I ask here?" is almost two pages long! At the very least, the first paragraph could land in the 'ask question' page, though chaning the FAQ a bit could help.

Comment: We don't want to change something fundamental about our site to fix a largely nonexistent problem.  We don't even get 1/month of these misguided souls. Not worth it.

Comment: @mxyzplk, Fair enough, you've all have a good point.

Answer (score 13):

This clue already exists. Open an incognito window and you'll see:

[image]

If they don't get a clue after seeing this than the best we can do is educate them post facto.

Comment: Oh, hadn't thought about doing that.